# Windows 8.1 Update

Tags: windows, mouse, windows-8.1, updates, touchscreen

Not much earlier today, I read of an update for Windows 8.1 that would seem to bleed the classical and Modern UIs together by doing things such as adding the minimize and close buttons to the corner of a Modern app. The article I read states that these will only be visible if one moves their mouse in the top-right corner of the window. This leads into my question. The article says that the OS will detect what kind of PC you're using and enable this based on that. My PC is an Acer Aspire M5-583P-6428 running Windows 8.1 64-bit, with a 10-point capacitive touchscreen. I rarely use the trackpad, but I do use an external mouse sometimes, especially when I use the PC for my games. Also, I've noticed that Battlelog (this is around the time of the Battlefield 4 Open Beta, which I participated in) recognizes my PC as a tablet because of the screen. My question is this. Will Windows recognize my computer as a tablet because of the touch screen, or a laptop because it is truly a laptop computer? It would be much appreciated if I could get some assistance relating to this.

Comment: The update has not been released yet.  Once the update is install you can change the configuration if you want.  The update won't be released until next week

Comment: What I am talking about is an update to Windows 8.1 itself, if that's not what you're thinking of. The news article I read is due to launch on April 8th.

Comment: The `Acer Aspire M5-583P-6428` is a laptop with a touchscreen.  It does not fit the criteria to be a tablet.

Comment: @kinokijuf - The final bits have had not been released until yesterday.

Comment: That is true. I just want to point out that back when the BF4 Open beta was out, Battlelog wouldn't let me edit my emblem on it, stating that I couldn't change it on a tablet. Either is possible though.

Comment: @crayzeedude - The error message makes no sense.  BF4 doesn't care if you use a tablet, laptop, or a desktop.  Without the exact error I can't comment on what it actually meant.

Comment: I agree. If it's possible to still edit my emblem even without BF4 purchased, I'll screenshot and direct you to it.

Comment: @Ramhound The final MSU bits have leaked some time ago

Comment: @kinokijuf - Fine;  Its not really all that important.

Answer (score 0):

I also use a Windows 8.1 Tablet and when I attach a mouse to it I see the title bar of the Store Apps when I move the mouse pointer to the top.

The only thing which is not added to startscreen is the new shutdown button

[image]

if you use touch hardware.